# Create a DataFrame from list and 2D list together

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a list and a tuple list (2D list) for the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
X,y =iris.data,iris.target
models=[]
models.append(('LR',LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LRL',LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty=l2')))
models.append(('ETCL',ExtraTreesClassifier()))

names=[]
feature=[]
for name, model in models:
    model.fit(X,y)
    feature_idx=SelectFromModel(model,prefit=True).get_support()
    feature.append((name, feature_idx))
names.append(name)
```

I've created a dataframe from the lists and 2DS list in two steps by concating the dataframes as

```
feature_sel_df=pd.DataFrame.from_items(feature)
feature_name=pd.Series(X.columns).to_frame('Feature')

feature_df=pd.concat([feature_name,feature_sel_df],axis=1)
```

Can I create feature_df directly from the list and 2D list ?

Comment: provide sample data in this case list of list which you want to convert into dataframe

Comment: Data added at the top now